# Exception while inserting mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, insert

I have generated a mysql table from script like below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Record` (
  `RecordID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `URL` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RecordID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The problem is I cant insert any value to the table like this way

```
sql = "INSERT INTO  test.'Record' " + "('URL') VALUES " + "(?);";
```

either this way

```
    sql = "INSERT INTO  'test'.'Record' values(?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = db.conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            stmt.setString(1, URL);
            stmt.execute();
```

this the exception message

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test'.'Record' values
```

What is the correct way of doing this .

Comment: Remove single quote from database name and table name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove single quote from database name and table name.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO test.Record values(?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = db.conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            stmt.setString(1, URL);
            stmt.execute();
```

Instead of single quote you can use backquote (`) sign. It will work.